# How to insert entities with self-referencing foreign key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
public partial class DataLog
{
  [Key]
  public Guid ID { get; set; }

  public Guid? RelDataLogID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("RelDataLogID")]
  public DataLog RelDataLog { get; set; }

  //other properties ommitted... 
}
```

I have a list of `DataLog` entities and I try to insert them to an SQLite database.

Unfortunately, I get an exception at the first entity:

> SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

It is obvious, I try to insert an item that references an entity that does not exist.

If I set the `RelDataLogID` key to null, the insert works but the navigation becomes invalid then, so it is not a good workaround.

What is the best practice in this case? Should I remove the `ForeignKey` attribute (though it seems to cause potential inconsistency) or find some sorting that considers the references?

Comment: I don't think you need this: public Guid? RelDataLogID { get; set; }. The DataLog object RelDataLog's id should be the property populated along with any other field within the class.

Comment: @user10728126 That RelDataLogID is the field that represents that foreign key as key like a database field. What else should assure that the foreign object is valid?

Comment: the id you're trying to enter as the primary key, does that key exist in the RelDataLog table? If not, then you'll have to add that entity first prior to adding the DataLog entity.

Comment: @user10728126 That is the problem: saving the first entity fails as its RelDataLogID refers to a `DataLog` entity that has not been inserted yet. If I begin to check if the `DataLog` with that ID exists I also have to check if its RelDataLogID refers to a valid entity, and so on, it is a neverending loop...

Comment: First, are you using `Add` / `AddRange` method? If yes, at the time of calling `Add`, is  `RelDataLog` navigation property populated or just the `RelDataLogID` FK property?

Comment: If you're inserting a foreign key field you have to check if it exists in the RelDataLog table or get the foreign key exception to fire and then insert it into the RelDataLog. Either way is standard practice. The error is doing what it's supposed to do...prevent you from entering in orphan records.

Comment: @user10728126 There is no `RelDataLog` table..only `DataLog`. The problem is that they are the same type but the _order_ of insert is what causing the problem. @Ivan Stoev Only the ID is set, the navigation property is null.

Comment: Your database is wrong but to get past the error you're receiving, just remove the foreign key constraint atop of the RelDataLog object and you'll be able to insert. You have to put in null for RelDataLogID because of the nullable type Guid? You can always default it like: public Guid? RelDataLogID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

Comment: @user10728126 Why is it wrong? Because there is a self-referencing key property? The problem that I copy data and the keys _are set_, so when I insert, the key check fails. I don't need default value.